# How do I get the domain name in Windows 7

Tags: delphi, dll, windows-7, dns, delphi-2007

I've written a dll that runs an Excel add-in (some years ago).

I use this code to retrieve the domain name and that works fine in Windows XP, but it fails in Windows 7.
**Only** if I run as administrator does it work.
However I don't want to run as administrator because this code is part of an Excel add-in dll and Excel cannot find the user's files if running as admin.

```
MyReg:= TRegistry.Create;

MyReg.RootKey:= HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
MyReg.OpenKey(RegKeyWin7,false);
NetworkID2:= lowercase(trim(MyReg.ReadString(RegValWin7)));
MyReg.CloseKey;

FreeAndNil(MyReg);

FNetworkOK:= (NetworkID2 = OKRes4);
//Temp check to pinpoint the problem.
if FNetWorkOK = false then ShowMessage('Error wrong domain: '+NetworkID2)
else ShowMessage('all ok');
```

How do I retrieve the domain name in Windows 7 using Delphi under normal privileges?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [NetWkstaGetInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370663%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) in the Win32 API, requesting info via `level` value = 100.

> Return information about the
>   workstation environment, including
>   platform-specific information, the
>   name of the domain and the local
>   computer, and information concerning
>   the operating system. The bufptr
>   parameter points to a WKSTA_INFO_100
>   structure.

Comment: Thanks, Checked it out, I need to be a authenticated user to access, so I think normal users have the privileges run this. Kind of hate to have to use these horrible Win_api functions, was hoping that was a Delphi wrapper function for that.

Comment: Yes, Win32 does it all but can be ugly.

Comment: @Johan: there are many Delphi examples for NetWkstaGetInfo: http://www.google.com/search?q=NetWkstaGetInfo+delphi, for instance this one http://www.delphi-central.com/tutorials/delphi_user_list.aspx

Comment: @Jeroen, Yea, I found this one: http://www.delphi-central.com/tutorials/delphi_user_list.aspx He! that's the same one you found, anyway good one because it works on the devel-machine. Lets see if it works in production.

Comment: @Johan - glad to hear it, all the best